# How to set the background color for the unfilled space in CSS where the child element does not completely fill the parent element?

Tags: css

How to set the background color for the unfilled space in CSS where the child element does not completely fill the parent element?

What I have so far:

```css
.container {
  background-image: url("https://images.pexels.com/photos/38136/pexels-photo-38136.jpeg?w=1260&h=750&dpr=2&auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb");
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.element1,
.element2 {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: aliceblue;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="element1">
    123
  </div>
  <div class="element2">
    5555
  </div>
</div>
```

I want the space outside of the element to be white, while element 1 and element 2 display an image.

Like this

[image]

**updates**

I changed my approach and achieved the desired result. I apologize for not describing the problem clearly.

But I still want to know if there is a way to achieve my previous approach. The container has a background image, and I want to set the background of the elements as transparent so that its area shows the background image, while the background outside of the elements is set to white.

By doing this, I won't need complex calculations, and I can freely change the number and size of elements, which will make it more interesting.

```
<style>
    body {
        margin: 0;
        display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: rgba(9, 151, 104, 0.808);
}

.container {
  width:300px;
  height: 300px;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3,1fr);
}

.child-element {
    border: none;
  background-image: url("https://images.pexels.com/photos/732547/pexels-photo-732547.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&w=1260&h=750&dpr=1");
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 1px #fff;
  background-size: 300px 300px;
  position: relative;
  top: 20px;
  background-position-y: -200px;
}

.child-element:nth-child(3n+1){
    left: -20px;
    background-position-x: 0;
}

.child-element:nth-child(3n+2){
    left: 0;
    background-position-x: -100px;
}

.child-element:nth-child(3n){
    left: 20px;
    background-position-x: -200px;
}
.child-element:nth-child(-n+6){
    top: 0;
    background-position-y: -100px;
}
.child-element:nth-child(-n+3){
    top: -20px;
    background-position-y: 0;
}

</style>

<div class="container">
  
  <div class="child-element">
  </div>
  <div class="child-element">
  </div>
  <div class="child-element">
  </div>
  <div class="child-element">
  </div>
  <div class="child-element">
  </div>
  <div class="child-element">
  </div>
  <div class="child-element">
  </div>
  <div class="child-element">
  </div>
  <div class="child-element">
  </div>
  

</div>
```

Comment: Is simply adding a white boarder to the child elements an option? (It would achieve what you have shown, but give slightly different results if, e.g. there were an odd number of child elements in those two columns)

Comment: You seem to have eight elements in your posted image; or at least eight image segments?

Comment: I am having a hard time trying to tell what you actually want here. _"while element 1 and element 2 display an image"_ - but they only have a background-color in your example? Are they supposed to contain an `<img>` element, or do you want to apply a background-image to them? _"I want the space outside of the element to be white"_ - you mean the space left over within the dimensions of `.container`? That would mean that there where you currently _have_ set a background-image, you actually only want a white background-color instead ...?

Comment: I think I understand - mostly from discarding the posted HTML and CSS - what you *might* want, but unless you clarify your question (by editing it, to address the issues raised by myself and CBroe) I'm not prepared to offer an answer.

Answer (score 0):

IF a CSS grid would allow style of the "gap" that would be; alas there is no such thing SO you need to put borders on and style that appropriately.
Here is a "pretty ugly" example with most likely way too much CSS for this.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-size: 16px;
}

.container {
  background-image: url("https://images.pexels.com/photos/38136/pexels-photo-38136.jpeg?w=1260&h=750&dpr=2&auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb");
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border: 3px solid #FFFFFF;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-gap: 0;
}

.container>* {
  border: 3px solid #FFFFFF;
  text-align: center;
}

.child-element.element1,
.child-element.element2 {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: aliceblue;
  color: blue;
}

.child-element {
  margin: 0;
  border: 3px solid #FFFFFF;
  text-align: center;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  font-size: 2rem;
  height: 4em;
  padding: 1em;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="child-element element1">
    123
  </div>
  <div class="child-element element2">
    5555
  </div>
  <div class="child-element">
    tester out 1
  </div>
  <div class="child-element">
    tester out 2
  </div>
  <div class="child-element">
    tester out 3
  </div>
  <div class="child-element">
    tester out 4
  </div>
  <div class="child-element">
    tester out 5
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You understand what I mean!